# Could someone walk through how bind in the state monad is implemented ( among other things )?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

Despite reading through the really clear explanation in LYAH, and then Haskell Wiki, and some other stuff, I am still confused about how the state monad is *implemented*. I think I understand what it is though I'm not confident.

So let's say I have some trivial data type:

```
data Simple a = Top a 
  deriving ( Show )
```

And this:

```
newtype SimpleState a = SimpleState { applySimple :: Int -> ( a, Int ) }
```

I then make SimpleState a monad

```
instance Monad SimpleState where
    return x = SimpleState $ \s -> ( x, s )
    st >>= g = SimpleState $ \s -> let ( x, s' ) = applySimple st s in applySimple ( g x ) s'
```

Question 1: How is the lambda taking in s ( for state ) as a parameter? How is it passed in?

Question 2: if `applySimple` is taking in one parameter in its function signature, why do I have `applySimple st s` inside the lambda? Why is `applySimple`applied twice?

Even more confusing, this thing changes the state:

```
tic :: SimpleState Int
tic = SimpleState $ \s -> ( s, s + 1 )
```

Question 3. What is this? Why is it doing some sort of action on the SimpleState but its signature is not a function?

So now I could pass tic into this function:

```
incr :: Simple a -> SimpleState ( Simple ( a, Int ) ) 
incr ( Top a ) = do 
  v <- tic
  return ( Top ( a, v ) )
```

Question 4: could I / how would I use tic with `>>=` ?

And by using it like so:

```
applySimple ( incr ( Top 1 ) ) 3
```

I get this:

```
(Top (1,3),4)
```

Again, `applySimple` is applied to two params, which confuses me.

In summary, I'm getting really hung up on the fact that the constructor `SimpleState` is taking in a function that takes in in s as a param, and have no idea where it's coming from how it's used in context.

Comment: You can come by [funprog chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24510/functional-programming) if you want to go step by step, it doesn't really fit in SO format

Comment: woa totally have never thought to use the chat feature but will from now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Question 1: How is the lambda taking in s ( for state ) as a
>   parameter? How is it passed in?

Let's use the classic definitions of `get` and `put`, defined as:

```
put :: Int -> SimpleState ()
put n = SimpleState (\_ -> ((), n))

get :: SimpleState Int
get = SimpleState (\s -> (s, s))
```

When you call `applySimple`, you unwrap the `SimpleState`, which exposes a function of type `Int -> (a, Int)`.  Then you apply that function to your initial state.  Let's try it out using some concrete examples.

First, we'll run the command `put 1`, with an initial state of `0`:

```
applySimple (put 1) 0

-- Substitute in definition of 'put'
= applySimple (SimpleState (\_ -> ((), 1))) 0

-- applySimple (Simple f) = f
(\_ -> ((), 1)) 0

-- Apply the function
= ((), 1)
```

Notice how `put` ignores the initial state and just replaces the right state slot with `1`, leaving behind `()` in the left return value slot.

Now let's try running the get command, using a starting state of `0`:

```
applySimple get 0

-- Substitute in definition of 'get'
= applySimple (SimpleState (\s -> (s, s))) 0

-- applySimple (SimpleState f) = f
= (\s -> (s, s)) 0

-- Apply the function
= (0, 0)
```

`get` just copies `0` into the left return value slot, leaving the right state slot unchanged.

So the way you pass your initial state into that lambda function is just by unwrapping the `SimpleState` newtype to expose the underlying lambda function and directly applying the lambda function to the initial state.

> Question 2: if applySimple is taking in one parameter in its function
>   signature, why do I have applySimple st s inside the lambda? Why is
>   applySimpleapplied twice?

That's because `applySimple`'s type is not `Int -> (a, Int)`.  It's actually:

```
applySimple :: SimpleState -> Int -> (a, Int)
```

This is a confusing aspect of Haskell's record syntax.  Whenever you have a record field like:

```
data SomeType { field :: FieldType }
```

... then `field`'s type is actually:

```
field :: SomeType -> FieldType
```

I know it's weird.

> Question 3. What is this? Why is it doing some sort of action on the
>   SimpleState but its signature is not a function?

The `SimpleState` newtype hides the function that it wraps.  `newtypes` can hide absolutely anything until you unwrap them.  Your `SimpleState` does have function inside of it, but all the compiler sees is the outer newtype until you unwrap it with `applySimple`.

> Question 4: could I / how would I use tic with >>= ?

You're making a mistake in your definition of `incr`.  The correct way to use `tic` would be like this:

```
ticTwice :: SimpleState ()
ticTwice = do
    tic
    tic
```

... which the compiler translates to:

```
ticTwice =
    tic >>= \_ ->
    tic
```

Using your definition of `(>>=)` and tic, you can prove that this increments the value by two:

```
tic >>= \_ -> tic

-- Substitute in definition of `(>>=)`
SimpleState (\s ->
    let (x, s') = applySimple tic s
    in  applySimple ((\_ -> tic) x) s')

-- Apply the (\_ -> tic) function
SimpleState (\s ->
    let (x, s') = applySimple tic s
    in  applySimple tic s')

-- Substitute in definition of `tic`
SimpleState (\s ->
    let (x, s') = applySimple (SimpleState (\s -> (s, s + 1))) s
    in  applySimple (SimpleState (\s -> (s, s + 1))) s'

-- applySimple (SimpleState f) = f
SimpleState (\s ->
    let (x, s') = (\s -> (s, s + 1)) s
    in  (\s -> (s, s + 1)) s'

-- Apply both functions
SimpleState (\s ->
    let (x, s') = (s, s + 1)
    in  (s', s' + 1)

-- Simplify by getting rid of unused 'x'
SimpleState (\s ->
    let s' = s + 1
    in  (s', s' + 1)

-- Simplify some more:
SimpleState (\s -> s + 1, s + 2)
```

So you see that when you chain two `tic`s using `(>>=)`, it combines them into a single stateful function that increments the state by `2`, and returns the state plus `1`.

Comment: Awesomely detailed answer, thanks for walking through the do notation with me

Answer (score 11):

Okay, you've smooshed a bunch of questions into one post...

### 1. Where does the lambda parameter `s` come from?

```
return x = SimpleState $ \s -> ( x, s )
```

If you look at your constructor, `SimpleState`, you'll notice that it takes a function of type `Int -> (a, Int)` as an argument.  So the lambda is used in order to give us a function of the correct type.  Lambda is just one way of making a function.

The reason that a function is necessary is because only through the function parameter is it possible to access the current state of the state monad.

### 2. Why does `applySimple` take two parameters?

That's because it's a field accessor.

```
data Point = Point { x :: Int, y :: Int }
```

What is the type of `x`?  Well, it's `Point -> Int`.  It extracts a field from a `Point` value.

```
origin = Point 0 0
potOfGold = Point 15 3

main = putStrLn $ "Pot of gold is at (" ++ show (x potOfGold) ++ ", " ++
                  show (y potOfGold) ++ ")"
```

Clearly, `x` does not have type `Int` because it is different for each `Point`.  Likewise,

```
newtype MyState a = MyState { runState :: Int -> (a, Int) }
```

What is the type of `runState`?  Well, it's `MyState -> Int -> (a, Int)`.  It extracts a field (the only field) from a `MyState a` value.

### Why is `tic` not a function?

Monadic actions do not need to be functions.  For example, think about the code `putStrLn`:

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, world."
```

It makes sense to you that `putStrLn` does something because it is a function, right?  Well, you are right that it does something but your reasoning is wrong.  You are using imperative intuition for a functional language.  Strictly speaking, `putStrLn` does NOT print anything, it is a function that returns a monadic action, and the resulting monadic action prints `"Hello, world."`.

```
printHello :: IO ()
printHello = putStrLn "Hello, world."
```

Obviously, this does something.  It is not a function since it does not take parameters.  Get this through your head if you want to understand Haskell: "do something" is a property of monadic actions and it has *nothing* to do with functions.

### 4. Could I / how would I use `tic` with `>>=` ?

"How do I use feature X with feature Y" is near the top of my list of pet peeves, as far as questions on Stack Overflow are concerned.  It's like asking "how do I use water in the kitchen" and I say "you could mop the floor" but really you were thirsty and wanted to drink the water.  Better to ask a question like, "How do I use water to clean the floor?" or "How do I use water to quench my thirst?"  These questions are answerable.

So, the answer to question 4 is "Yes, you can use `tic` with `>>=`."  And, "How you use it depends on what you want to do."

**Footnote:** I suggest that you conform to predominant coding styles, e.g., `f (x y)` instead of `f ( x y )`, since it will help people read your code.

Comment: Yeah question 4 was poorly phrased, I wanted to in a round about way ask someone to expand the do notation but didn't because I thought I should be able to do (heh) that by now

Answer (score 4):

In the `State` monad, bind composes stateful functions (similar to the usual `(.)` composition. When you're done composing your computation (i.e. all the stuff in your `do` block) you can then *run* the thing on your initial state *value*.

> Question 1: How is the lambda taking in s ( for state ) as a parameter? How is it passed in?

The lambda binding right after `SimpleState` is the *initial* state value that you ultimately run your monadic computation on. This would be more clear if you were using a construction where your state could change type, rather than one restricted to `s`.

> Why is applySimple applied twice?

What's happening concretely is that `applySimple` is just extracting your `Int -> ( a, Int )` from the `newtype` wrapper; then that function is applied to what follows (`s`). This is the same idea as doing: `($) (+1) 1`.

> Why is it doing some sort of action on the SimpleState but its signature is not a function?

I think understanding that the bound `\s->` is your *initial* TBD state, and thinking in terms of bind as composition will get you there. This is a very different beast from a monad like `Maybe`.

FWIW a number of people seem to have found this [old tutorial](http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/) I wrote helpful.